# Best practice using docker inside Jenkins?

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Hi I'm learning how to use Jenkins integrated with Docker and I don't understand what should I do to communicate them.

I'm running Jenkins inside a Docker container and I want to build an image in a pipeline. So I need to execute some docker commands inside the Jenkins container.

So the thing here is where docker come from. I understand that we need to bind mount the docker host daemon (socket) to the Jenkins container but this container still needs the binaries to execute Docker.

I have seen some approaches to achieve this and I'm confused what should I do. I have seen:

- bind mount the docker binary (/usr/local/bin/docker:/usr/bin/docker)
- installing docker in the image
- if I'm not wrong the blue ocean image comes with Docker pre-installed (I have not found any documentation of this)

Also I don't understand what Docker plugins for Jenkins can do for me.

Thanks!

Comment: I have a similar infrastructure but I have never executed a build on the jenkins master. You can add another slave(with installed docker engine) to jenkins and than you are able to run your jobs on the slave i.e. outside of your docker container.

Comment: bind mounting the docker binary is the interesting part i think.
It saves to maintain a compatible docker client version in the jenkins image.
However, I have difficulties getting it to work!

Answer (score 1):

Docker has a client server architecture. The server is the docker deamon and the client is basically the command line interface that allows you to execute `docker ...` from the command line.

Thus when running Jenkins inside Docker you will need access to connect to the deamon. This is acheieved by binding the `/var/run/docker.sock` into the container.

At this point you need something to communicate with the Deamon which is the server. You can either do that by providing access to docker binaries. This can be achived by either mounting the docker binaries, or installing the 
client binaries inside the Jenkins container.

Alternatively, you can communicate with the deamon using the Docker Rest API without having the docker client binaries inside the Jenkins container. You can for instance [build an image using the API](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.30/#operation/ImageBuild).

> Also I don't understand what Docker plugins for Jenkins can do for me

The [Docker plugin for Jenkins](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Docker+Plugin) isn't useful for the use case that you described. This plugin allows you to provision Jenkins slaves using Docker. You can for instance run a compilation inside a Docker container that gets automatically provisioned by Jenkins

Answer (score 1):

It is not best practice to use Docker with Jenkins.  It is also not a bad practice. The relationship between Jenkins and Docker is not determined in such a manner that having Docker is good or bad.

Jenkins is a Continuous Integration Server, which is a fancy way of saying "a service that builds stuff at various times, according to predefined rules"

If your end result is a docker image to be distributed, you have Jenkins call your `docker build` command, collect the output, and report on the success / failure of the `docker build` command.

If your end result is not a docker image, you have Jenkins call your non-docker build command, collect the output, and report on the success / failure of the non-docker build.

How you have the build launched depends on how you would build the product.  Makefiles are launched with `make`, Apache Ant with `ant`, Apache Maven with `mvn package`, docker with `docker build` and so on.  From Jenkin's perspective, it doesn't matter, provided you provide a complete set of rules to launch the build, collect the output, and report the success or failure.

Now, for the 'Docker plugin for Jenkins'.  As @yamenk stated, Jenkins uses build slaves to perform the build.  That plugin will launch the build slave within a Docker container.  The thing built within that container may or may not be a docker image.

Finally, running Jenkins inside a docker container just means you need to bind your Docker-ized Jenkins to the external world, as @yamenk indicates, or you'll have trouble launching builds.

Answer (score 0):

Bind mounting the docker binary into the jenkins image only works if the jenkins images is "close enough" - it has to contain the required shared libraries!

So when sing a standard jenkins/jenkins:2.150.1 within an ubuntu 18.04 this is not working unfortunately. (it looked so nice and slim ;)

So the  the requirement is to build or find a docker image which contains a compatible docker client for the host docker service is.

Many people seem to install docker in their jenkins image....